# Correct Way of Implementing Java Interface Method

Tags: java, interface, methods

I have this interface

```
public interface MyInterface{
    Collection<T> Find(T t);
    Collection<T> FindAll();
    T FindById(int id);
    void Add(T t);
    void Remove(T t);
}
```

What must I do for the `T FindById(int id)` method if I need to be guaranteed that T will have an Id of type int? Should I create another interface that my object must extend to use FindById?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To really get that type-safety, as well as flexibility for non-`int` identifiers, try something like:

```
public interface IdentifiedThing<I extends Serializable> {
    I getId();
}
```

You can then lock down the typing:

```
public interface MyInterface<I extends Serializable, IT extends IdentifiedThing<I>> {
    Collection<IT> find(IT t);
    Collection<IT> findAll();
    IT findById(I id);
    void add(IT t);
    void remove(IT t);
}
```

(I've fixed your method capitalization to Java-style too ;-)

Comment: The only downside is that id must be an object, so you will suffer autoboxing/unboxing if you need to convert ints to Integers.

Comment: @sk. true - as with almost all things in programming, it's a tradeoff. Robert may feel the compile-time safety is worth the runtime performance hit.

Comment: I'm confused as to what this does. This guarantees type-safety and that the object will have an id?

Comment: @Robert exactly. You're making sure that `MyInterface` will only deal with `IT` instances, but **further**, you're ensuring that these `IT`s actually **have** an identifier which is of the same type as that specified as the parameter to `findById()`

Comment: @millhouse This is very nifty. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I create another interface that my object must extend to use
>   FindById?

Yes (although it is not specific to the `FindById` method).  More precisely, you should have another interface that can guarantee that your class will have an integer ID that you can access.  Something like this should suffice:

```
public interface HasId {
    int GetId();
}
```

Then you can make your `MyInterface` class use `T extends HasId`, as follows:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends HasId> {
    Collection<T> Find(T t);
    Collection<T> FindAll();
    T FindById(int id);
    void Add(T t);
    void Remove(T t);
}
```

Comment: So in this case if I pass in an integer like 2 in my implementation class I could say `return T.GetId() == t`?

Comment: `FindById` takes in an integer, so you can just call `FindById(x.GetId())`, where `x` is the `HasId` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept only specific objects into your collection like here it's `Entity` which will have `id` for sure

```
interface Entity {
    int getId();
}

interface MyCollection<T extends Entity> {
    T findById(int id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a template way here. And there is something wrong , it should be

```
public interface MyInterface<T>{
```

T is the template type.

When you implement this interface , a type should be given to replace the T , if there isn't , T will be replaced by Object .

I think you are right that if you want to guarantee there is an id of type int in the return type.